# aws Lambda bcrypt

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, bcrypt

Is it possible to require a node.js module in aws lambda that can not be required by default?

I'm trying to implement a password hashing function using the bcrypt algorithm but

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

won't work. I've searched the internet now for quite some time but couldn't find a fitting solution. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/
 doesn't help either since I don't have an EC2 instance with Node.js installed. I think there must be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible but requires you to attach the `node_modules` folder as well.

This [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html) will walk you through, it's very simple.

Comment: For this scenario I went with pbkdf2 but thanks for the reply, I'm sure I'll need it in the near future.